# AngularJS - how to send int[] to an action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Ok, I have a checkbox list showing roles data on my project.
To retrieve these roles, I'm doing this below:

```
$scope.Roles = [];
$scope.init = function() {

    $.get('/Navigation/NavigationNewDependencies', {}, function(result) {

        for (var I = 0; I < result.Roles.length; ++I) {

            var splited = result.Roles[I].split(";");
            $scope.Roles.push({ id: splited[0], name: splited[1], checked: false });
        }

        $scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

And showing this way:

```
<div>
    Roles:
    <ul data-ng-repeat="role in Roles">
        <li><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="role.checked" />{{role.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Ok, it works properly. I want to send to an action these checked roles on the form, you know? How can I do it?

I'm trying to do the POST this way below:

```
$scope.getSelectedRoles = function () {

    var selectedRoles = [];
    for (var I = 0; I < $scope.Roles.length; ++I) {
        if ($scope.Roles[I].checked == true) {

            var role = $scope.Roles[I];
            selectedRoles.push({ RoleId: role.id, RoleName: role.name });
        }
    }
    return selectedRoles;
}

$scope.submit = function () {

    $.post('/Navigation/New', {
        title: $scope.model.NavigationName,
        description: $scope.model.NavigationDescription,
        controller: $scope.model.NavigationController,
        action: $scope.model.NavigationAction,
        roles: $scope.getSelectedRoles()
    }, function (result) {

        if (result.IsValid) {
            window.location.href = result.ReturnUrl;
        } else {
            alert(result.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

... But I can't get the right selected roles on the form.

First: How can I get the selected roles with some computed property or something else?

Second: the right parameters to receive this selected roles are `params int[] roles`?

Thank you all!

Comment: plaese put code on jsfiddle/plunker/jsbin

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
//Ends up being the array of ints for the action.
//You can put this in any event handler you want, like another function attached
//to a ngCLick directive
var selectedRoles = $scope.Roles.filter(function(role) { return role.checked}).
                        .map(function(role) { return role.id});

$.put('/Navigation/NavigationNewDependencies', {roles: selectedRoles})
    .success(function(){//Do something cool on successfully sending to server});
```

This assumes a few things:

1. Your '/Navigation/NavigationNewDependencies' action can handle 'put's
2. The array of ints you are passing to the action is an array of the selected role ids

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to do a standard, non-ajax form submit and hit an MVC controller action. If that's the case, update your checkbox markup to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="role.checked" value="{{ role.id }}" name="roles" />
```

Then wrap it all in a form tag with its action attribute pointing to an action method with a single parameter named "roles" of type int[].

**UPDATE**:

@Kiwanax, this should do it:

Angular Controller:

```
function RolesCtrl($scope, $http) {

// use Angular's $http service to communicate with the server
// won't need to call $scope.$apply();

$http.get('/Navigation/NavigationNewDependencies').success(function (result) {
    // try to send json object array from the server (instead of a string)
    $scope.roles = result; 

    // but you don't have control over it, 
    // process your string result the way you are currently doing it 
});

$scope.getSelectedRoleIds = function () {
    var result = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.roles, function (value, key) {
        if (value.checked) result.push(value.id);
    });

    return result;
};

$scope.postData = function () {
    $http.post(
        '/Navigation/New',
        { roles: $scope.getSelectedRoleIds() }
    ).success(function () {
        alert('done'); 
    });
};
```

}

View (use the *ng-submit* attribute to offload form submission handling to Angular):

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="RolesCtrl">

<form ng-submit="postData()">
    <ul data-ng-repeat="role in roles">
        <li><input type="checkbox" ng-model="role.checked"/>{{role.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button>submit roles</button>
</form>
```

MVC Controller's (Navigation) Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult New(int[] roles)
    {
        // process roles Ids

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: They are using angular, so this isn't the correct approach.  Also, the form submittal you are proposing wouldn't match the action parameters he stated.

Comment: It doesn't work, @m1kael. I've edited my topic and add my POST code. See above, please. Thanks!